# ID of document library to use in CSS

Tags: document-library, css

I am looking to use an ID or Class attribute of a document library in a CSS file. I need to be able to highlight my current tab on my navigational menu.

I can add a CEWP with a text file containing a body ID (to my document library), then referencing that in my CSS file but it doesn't work across different views of the document library as the CEWP disappears when changing views.

Are there any ID attributes that remain the same over the whole document library no matter what view you're in?

Thanks

Comment: I't hard to help with the info you give. Maybe some markup of the different document views would help?

Comment: I ended up just using jQuery for this. Put it in my master page in a script tag.

    if ( document.location.href.indexOf('<string in URL - I used the name of the document library') > -1 ) {
   $('UL#topnav A.SecondTab').css('background-image', 'url(highlightedtab.jpg)');
  }

Used several if statements because each tab has a different class name, e.g. FirstTab, SecondTab etc.

Comment: OK, good you found a solution. Why don't you write that down as an answer to your question an later mark it as the correct answer so other people find it more attractive to read your question if it has a working answer?

Comment: Couldn't reply to my own question within 3 hours or something - I'll try it again. 
- Posted it but can't accept for 17 hours :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using jQuery for this. Put it in my master page in a script tag.

```
if ( document.location.href.indexOf('<string in URL - I used the name of the document library') > -1 ) {
        $('UL#topnav A.SecondTab').css('background-image', 'url(highlightedtab.jpg)');
    }
```

Used several if statements because each tab has a different class name, e.g. FirstTab, SecondTab etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the ID is not the best selector for your CSS rule? Why not something containing the title?

Answer (score 0):

Try with Below sample Custom CSS Codes apply only Current Library.

#MSOZoneCell_  --  Common for all be placed on First,

WebPartWPQ7   ---  Find Out Web part Id using F12 (web developer tools),

.ms-vb2       --   Global Document Library ID's

## MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ7 .ms-vb2 {

```
LINE-HEIGHT: 1.2; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif; FONT-SIZE: 70pt;
```

}

## MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ7 .ms-itmhover{

```
display: none;
}
```

## MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ7 .ms-vh-icon{

display: none;
}

## MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ7 .ms-vh2{

display: none;
}